# How to set Windows shell env variable? The term 'C:\Users\stojko\' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: windows, powershell

I thought this would work

```
PS C:\Users\stojko> $env:Path = C:\Users\stojko\
C:\Users\stojko\ : The term 'C:\Users\stojko\' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the
path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:13
+ $env:Path = C:\Users\stojko\
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\stojko\:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

If I  go for

```
$env
```

shows nothing.

```
$profile output

C:\Users\stojko\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
```

How to set up envs on WIndows 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a string you need to set:

```
$env:Path = "C:\Users\stojko\"
```

and if you want to add it to the existing list:

```
$env:Path += ";C:\Users\stojko\"
```

Comment: $env is empty again.

Comment: If you want to see all environment vars, you use `Get-ChildItem env:`